# Filter and sort table based XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt and have done some research and read a brief book and looked at many examples but I'm afraid I just don't get it. I've only done simple procedural coding before and I guess I'm missing something. I understand a very basic example but when I try to transform my own data I am completely lost. Boo hoo hoo. It is soooo frustrating knowing that I don't it! I really feel like a hack :(

Anyway, I generated the following XML from a table in MS Word. The table ID and Row and Column IDs of each cell are given so it is possible to know how things relate to each other.

Now I want to present the data in a pick list and basically want to:
1. Filter the data on, say [Name='p_fld_parent_ref' and Value='RM12']. The data with the matching "rows" (i.e. all the nodes with the matching RowID) is what I want.
2. I also want to sort that filtered data on the column (cell) with name [p_fld_date_received]. I included a @dateSerial attribute specifically to make the sorting easier.

In the example data I should get any "rows" of data with a parent reference of 'RM12' sorted by date received. I want to use the data in the [p_fld_quantity_available] cell.

I've wasted about 3 days on this and gotten absolutely nowhere. Normally you start to get somewhere but with xslt I've gotten nowhere. Strange.

Here is one "row" of my data (sorry, I pasted the XML but don't know how to format it for reading - can someone let me know how to display it in the right format? Thanks.):

```
<Root><Data><Element><Name>p_fld_ref</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>P</KeyType><ID>1</ID><Value>SKU1</Value><Description>Ref</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>SKUn</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>1</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_parent_ref</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>F</KeyType><ID>2</ID><Value>RM12</Value><Description>Parent Ref</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>CPLn,RMn</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>2</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_item_no</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>3</ID><Value>ZRMH06</Value><Description>Item Code</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>3</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_type</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>4</ID><Value>RM</Value><Description>Type</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>CA or RM</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>4</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_serial_no</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>5</ID><Value>120201</Value><Description>Serial No.</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>5</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_name_1</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>6</ID><Value>Product Name 1</Value><Description>Name 1</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>6</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_name_2</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>7</ID><Value>Product Name 1 Lang 2</Value><Description>Name 2</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>7</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_location</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>8</ID><Value/><Description>Location</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>8</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_receipt_no</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>9</ID><Value/><Description>Receipt No.</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>9</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_supplier</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>10</ID><Value/><Description>Supplier</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>10</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_supplier_ref</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>11</ID><Value/><Description>Supplier Ref</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Sn</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>11</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_supplier_batchno</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>12</ID><Value/><Description>Supplier Batch No.</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>12</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_supplier_coa</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>13</ID><Value/><Description>CoA Number</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>13</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_box_sample</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>14</ID><Value/><Description>Box to sample</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Text</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>14</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_number_boxes</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>15</ID><Value/><Description>Number of Containers</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>15</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_quantity_total</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>16</ID><Value/><Description>Total Quantity</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>16</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_date_received</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>17</ID><Value dateSerial="20130217000000">17-Feb-2013</Value><Description>Date Received</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Date</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>17</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_date_retest</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>18</ID><Value dateSerial="20140217000000">17-Feb-2014</Value><Description>Re-Test Date</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Date</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>18</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_date_expire</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>19</ID><Value dateSerial="20160217000000">17-Feb-2016</Value><Description>Expiry Date</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Date</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>19</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_date_released</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>20</ID><Value dateSerial="20130217000000">17-Feb-2013</Value><Description>Release Date</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Date</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>20</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_quantity_reserved</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>21</ID><Value>20000</Value><Description>Reserved Quantity</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>21</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_quantity_used</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>22</ID><Value>0</Value><Description>Used Quantity</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>22</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_quantity_available</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>23</ID><Value>20000</Value><Description>Available Quantity</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Number</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>23</ColumnID></Element><Element><Name>p_fld_status</Name><Key>SKU1</Key><KeyType>D</KeyType><ID>24</ID><Value/><Description>Status</Description><Required>True</Required><dataType>Q, R or X</dataType><parmType>1</parmType><TableID>6</TableID><RowID>3</RowID><ColumnID>24</ColumnID></Element></Root>
```

Comment: I made your "XML" code readable, but it isn't wellformed XML document. Please, correct and make it indented and multiline -- in its present form the question is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each row is represented by a `<Data>` element (incidentally, you're missing the end tag of the `<Data>` element in this sample), this should do the filter/sorting part:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates
          select="Data[Element[Name='p_fld_parent_ref']/Value='RM12']">
        <xsl:sort select="Element[Name='p_fld_date_received]/Value/@dateSerial" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll need to define a template for how you want your `<Data>` elements presented, and probably something other than simply re-creating the `Root` element as I've done above. Something as simple as this might do the trick, if you just want to output text:

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:text>Item no.:</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Element[Name='p_fld_item_no']/Value" />
  <xsl:text> Quantity available:</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Element[Name='p_fld_quantity_available']/Value" />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><!-- New line -->
</xsl:template>
```

This isn't a complete solution, but hopefully it'll give you enough pointers to figure out the rest.